# what is fsHandler.go rootDiskErr and rootInodeErr error in minishift/openshift

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, openshift, minishift

I see the below error messages in the minishift logs. The rootDiskErr and rootInodeErr error is from fsHandler.go. Is this error related to filedescriptor limits or this error indicates other issues. Could anyone explain about this error.

one similar issue can be found at [this](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/7769) url. complete minishift logs can be found at [this](https://github.com/get2arun/logs/blob/master/minishift_apiserver_connecttion_refused_error.log) url.

**error from minishift logs:**

> E0108 23:07:16.549830    5161 fsHandler.go:121] failed to collect
>   filesystem stats - rootDiskErr: du command failed on
>   /rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a09b3f23e1178c3234462141c1705d54081cdc3d5889a4e2f25858007dc555e4/diff
>   with output stdout: , stderr: du: cannot access
>   '/rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a09b3f23e1178c3234462141c1705d54081cdc3d5889a4e2f25858007dc555e4/diff':
>   No such file or directory
>    - exit status 1, rootInodeErr: cmd [ionice -c3 nice -n 19 find /rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a09b3f23e1178c3234462141c1705d54081cdc3d5889a4e2f25858007dc555e4/diff
>   -xdev -printf .] failed. stderr: find: '/rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a09b3f23e1178c3234462141c1705d54081cdc3d5889a4e2f25858007dc555e4/diff':
>   No such file or directory ; err: exit status 1, extraDiskErr: du
>   command failed on
>   /rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/bf134045f4a99315787771bb7933e2092e6bacd0db440a727578c346803ece6e
>   with output stdout: , stderr: du: cannot access
>   '/rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers/bf134045f4a99315787771bb7933e2092e6bacd0db440a727578c346803ece6e':
>   No such file or directory
>    - exit status 1

another similar issue is at 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66421

my minishift vm fs limit,

```
[docker@minishift ~]$ sysctl fs.file-nr
fs.file-nr = 2592   0   299016
```

Comment: "No such file or directory" seems pretty clear to me. It's trying to access the filesystem of a Docker container that doesn't exist. If you think this is a bug report it in the issue tracker.

Comment: @Peter, why is it trying to access the filesystem that doesn't exist. If some process is looking for the another process or anything that doesn't exist, I need to understand what is missing in the minishift.

Answer (score 1):

`No such file or directory`  happens when a container has not started or has already removed. Its **harmless** error

Comment: I am worried about the error messages like extraDiskErr and rootInodeErr. why minishift has to look for containers that has been removed already. how to trace from where this error's origin?

Comment: this is normal situation in asynchronous system where race condition happen. for instance,  pod has restarted with different name (new state + left over stale state),  still other component try to do some action with the stale resource.  Eventually, System fix itself.

Comment: Eventually, minishift  will remove stale resources, then warning or error will disappear.  That’s why k8s is following  `eventual consistency`  philosophy of distributed system